# CSS table height of rows not even

Tags: css, layout, position, css-tables

I am trying to create a 4x4 array of content using css tables. The cells should be evenly sized. I got a fix to a problem with the [cells going out of the parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776554/a-css-table-in-one-of-parallel-divs/17776631?noredirect=1#17776631). However that broke the height of the cells.

What is wrong here? All the rows should be 25% of the container, with the cells inheriting that. What seems to happen is the first row grows as much as it can, and the 3 remaining ones scale according to the content... Why?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

html,body {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}

div { 
    display: block;
}

#container {
    background-color: #CCF;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.sideBySide {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

#galleria {
    background-color:#0C0;
    left: 0px;
    right: 300px;
    width: auto;
}

#tagit {
    background-color: #099;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
}

#table {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
    position: relative;
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
}

.table-cell {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;

    padding: 20px;
}

.kuva {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    margin: 10px;

    background-color: #999;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="galleria" class="sideBySide">
            <div id="table">
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        Kuva1
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        Kuva2
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        Kuva3
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        Kuva4
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        Kuva1
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        Kuva2
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        Kuva3
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        Kuva4
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        text
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">
                        test
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="kuva">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tagit" class="sideBySide">.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: position:absolute or fixed kills display, so does float . Your mixing incompatible method together.Beside if these are data that deserve to be in a table, you should use a table and keep everything in the flow (position:static or relative;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Can you show me or point me to an example on how to do the layout. And can tables be used to fill the screen and then divide it evenly? Anyways I have heard that tables are bad for layouting...

Comment: just keeping everything in the flow and dispatching display table/table-row/table-cell to different levels you can get to something like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvDwk  (+ body{margin:0;} )

Comment: @GCyrillus That's exactly what I was after. I did not think about using the table more, and so on. I've been banging my head for so long because of this css (mostly "position: ..."). Maybe I'll learn someday. Would you mind turning that into an answer so I could accept it :)

Comment: glad it helped you, i'll make an answer of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just keeping everything in the flow and dispatching `display table/table-row/table-cell` to different levels you can get to something like this :
 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvDwk

To get rid of scrollbar when table can feet window do not forget to add  `body{margin:0;}`